# VS Code & pylance: Avoid squiggly line when import for python2/python3

Tags: visual-studio-code, importerror, pylance

I am working on code that supports python2 and python3 using the latest VS Code (v1.64.2) and pylance. My 'issue' is rather cosmetic, but still, I wonder if there is an option to get rid of the yellow squiggly line generated by pylance.

[image]

Is there a cleverer way to do the import or a way to tell pylance not to add the squiggly line? Thx!

For easier reproducibility, here to dummy code:

```py
try:
    # python2
    import xmlrpclib as xmlrpcclient
except ImportError:
    # python3
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpcclient
```

Comment: this really depends on what the warning is that pylance is giving

Comment: @Thering Most likely: `module xmlrpclib not found`. The current Python interpreter is 3.x and it does not have that module. Python 2.x is no longer supported by VSC. There is NO reason to develop Python 2.x code after 10 years of deprecation period.